# ajax enabled wcf service can use get only, can't use post

Tags: wcf

I am having ajax enabled wcf service which i can only call with get not post, although i can work with get but is there any reason for that? Is it required to have webmethod enabled or something?

here is how my wcf service looks

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ListingDisplay> Find(string postalCode)
```

I added [WebGet] when tried using jquery ajax, it wasn't required with asp.net scriptmanager.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `[WebInvoke()]` attribute - it should allow you to specify the POST, PUT, DELETE HTTP verbs, too, on your method.

Marc